# How to do select with where on second order ForeignKeyField in Python Peewee ORM?

Tags: python, database, select, orm, peewee

I'm using the (awesome) [Peewee ORM](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/) for my database needs and I now constructed a query as follows:

```
OauthCI.select().where(OauthCI.oauth.user.id == 2)
```

So `OauthCI` has a ForeignKeyField called `oauth`, which points to a table which in turn has a ForeignKeyField which is called `user`. Unfortunately, this gives me an error saying: `AttributeError: 'ForeignKeyField' object has no attribute 'user'`.

Does anybody know how I can select all records from `OauthCI` which has a `oauth` with a `user` with an `id` of 2? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is good but unfortunately peewee does not work that way right now. Here is how you do it instead:

```
OauthCI.select().join(Oauth).join(User).where(User.id == 2)
```

Comment: This still seems to be the case in July 2017.